# VirtualHost is not working under Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7

Tags: php, linux, centos, apache2, apache2.4

I'm trying to setup some VH in Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7 but without success since it's not working. This is what I've tried til now:

- Since in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` is this line `Include conf.modules.d/*.conf` then I create a file under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf` and place this inside it:

  ```
  NameVirtualHost *:80

  <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName webserver
       ServerAlias localhost devserver development
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Reload/Restart Apache service (tried both):

  ```
  service httpd reload|restart
  ```
- At Windows side edit the file `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add this line:

  ```
  192.168.3.131  webserver localhost devserver development # this is the IP of Apache Server
  ```
- Open the browser and tried: `http://webserver`, `http://devserver` and both goes to default Apache page so VH is not working.
- Place a file under `/var/www/html/index.php` with this lines `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` just to know which modules is Apache loading, this is the result:

  ```
  core mod_so http_core mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest 
  mod_authn_anon mod_authn_core mod_authn_dbd mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_file mod_authn_socache mod_authz_core 
  mod_authz_dbd mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_owner mod_authz_user mod_autoindex 
  mod_cache mod_cache_disk mod_data mod_dbd mod_deflate mod_dir mod_dumpio mod_echo mod_env mod_expires mod_ext_filter 
  mod_filter mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_log_config mod_logio mod_mime_magic mod_mime mod_negotiation 
  mod_remoteip mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_slotmem_plain mod_slotmem_shm mod_socache_dbm 
  mod_socache_memcache mod_socache_shmcb mod_status mod_substitute mod_suexec mod_unique_id mod_unixd mod_userdir 
  mod_version mod_vhost_alias mod_dav mod_dav_fs mod_dav_lock mod_lua prefork mod_proxy mod_lbmethod_bybusyness 
  mod_lbmethod_byrequests mod_lbmethod_bytraffic mod_lbmethod_heartbeat mod_proxy_ajp mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_connect 
  mod_proxy_express mod_proxy_fcgi mod_proxy_fdpass mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_scgi mod_systemd mod_cgi mod_php5
  ```

And apparently mod_vhost is loaded but is not working, did I miss something? Any help or advice around this? Maybe I forgot something but I read Apache docs and doesn't found something helpful

**Update: test1**

I made some changes to VH definition and now this is what I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName webserver
    #ServerAlias localhost devserver development

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all

        #Require local
        #Require 192.168.3.0/16
        #Require 192.168.1.0/16
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I'm getting a **403 Forbidden**

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

What is failing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thing that may be causing you problems :-

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Is no longer a valid syntax for Apache 2.4.x you should remove it completely.

On the Windows side once you have changed the HOSTS file, you need to reload the `DNS Client service`, so either reboot or better still, launch a command window using "Run as Administrator" and do this :-

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

Lastly, within your virtual hosts definition, it will help to tell apache from where it is allowed to accept connections to this Virtual Host like so :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName webserver
     ServerAlias localhost devserver development
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory  "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All

        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.3

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will allow access from the machine running apache `Require local` and from any ip address on the local network `Require ip 192.168.3`

Also I am not sure where Apache on unix puts its default document root but it might be an idea to differentiate your 3 domain names to different directories like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory  "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All

        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.3

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName webserver
     ServerAlias webserver
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/webserver
    <Directory  "/var/www/html/webserver">
        AllowOverride All

        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.3

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName development
     ServerAlias development
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/development
    <Directory  "/var/www/html/development">
        AllowOverride All

        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.3

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName devserver
     ServerAlias devserver
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/devserver
    <Directory  "/var/www/html/devserver">
        AllowOverride All

        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.3

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then put a simple html file in each directory saying 'Hello from Servername' and change servername in each file so you know you have got to the correct server.

**RE: Update test1.php**

```
Allow from all
```

Is not valid Apache 2.4 syntax either, unless you have loaded `LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so`

Even then it should be

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

So USE Apache **2.4** syntax

```
Require all granted
```

If you want to take the lazy route and allow access from the universe.

Comment: I removed the ServerAlias directive and leave only the ServerName just for test if that's the problem and is not. I removed the NameVirtualHost directive and that's not the problem either. Apache in CentOS and other RHEL based distros set DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html` so that's right at VH config. Finally after test in Windows with both command you left I tried this one too `ipconfig /flushdns` but accessing `webserver` takes me to the  the default "Welcome"

Comment: Yes but my point was that you have pointed all 3 of the domain names to the `/var/www/html` so they SHOULD all go to the same Virtual Host, which is the same place as your default localhost location. So how do you know if the Virtual Host definition is working?? So if you create 3 different VHOST all pointing at a diffeent directory you will know which ones actually work and which do not.

Comment: Well my logic says if all three domains point to the same address and that address has a `index.php` file if I call webserver or localhost or devserver any should show the index page or not? Maybe I'm wrong, right now I'm having another issue and I think that's the problem, here is the message I got `Unknown Authz provider: 192.168.3`

Comment: I think you need to activate mod_authz_host in Apache for the `Require ip` construct to work

Comment: It's loaded `LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so` :-\

Comment: I've disabled those lines temporary and now I'm getting a `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.` don't know why

Comment: Put the <Directory.....> section back into the VHOST. The `Require...` tells Apache who is allowed to access this site

Comment: See the additional note on my answer

Comment: You're right about the last comment but does wasn't the problem at all. What I did, after did a research, was change this `<Directory />  AllowOverride none Require all granted </Directory>` and that fix my issue, don't know if is the right choice but I'll continue playing with conf, anyway thx for your time and support

Comment: The `Require` wasn't working because I didn't see the `ip` before the subnet, now I fixed all the directories allowing access just from LAN (192.168.3.x) and not from the world (WAN)

Comment: Centos 6.4 smooth configuration, Centos 7 chaos, nightmare! I'm out

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on [jap1968](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26369197/5707814)'s post, *CentOS 7* comes with *SELinux*'s pain in the butt level set to `enforcing`. This causes all kinds of confusion when perfectly normal service configuration silently fail (*Apache*).

To disable *SELinux* you'll need to:

0) *[optional]* Crack open a shell and become root... or enjoy a shiny new, super fun, configuring *sudo* to let you do "root stuffs" project. Probably.

```
su -l
```

1) Get the current status of *SELinux*. Run `sestatus`:

```
sestatus
```

2) If *SELinux* is causing hair loss and premature aging you'll get something like this:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

3) Edit the `/etc/selinux/config` file. Change `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=permissive`. Doing this will set you up for endless joy next time you reboot. You'll end up with something like this:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
# SELINUX=enforcing
# ===> VOODOO HERE <===
SELINUX=permissive
# ===> END VOODOO  <===
#
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected. 
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

4) Disable *SELinux*. You can reboot at this point but it's easier to tell *SELinux* to take time off from tormenting you. Run `setenforce` to reset SELinux's enforcement level to match the `/etc/selinux/config` file:

```
setenforce 0
```

5) Check `sestatus` again:

```
sestatus
```

If everything went as expected `sestatus` will return something like this:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

6) Restart *Apache*. If your vhost's domain name is resolving to the server you're working on you'll see your shiny new virtual host:

```
# Restart apache:
systemctl restart httpd.service

# Be lazy by checking your virtual host from the command line:
curl www.example.com/new-file-that-only-exists-in-your-new-vhost.txt
```

6.5) Stop reading here. Or don't. I'm a message board post, not your Mom.

Everything below is beyond the scope of the original question and only included because **you really should be running with *SELinux* enabled**.

7) Work towards re-enabling selinux. Start by watching the selinux logs to see some awesome alphabet soup:

```
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

8) Be amazed at the depth of features, crazy number of poorly named utilities, and ugly UX mess that constitutes *SELinux*. You should probably put on your big boy pants and drink a whole pot of coffee before you dive in. Here's some Info:

- **CentoOS HowTo**: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux
- **Project**: http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page

Answer (score 3):

Be careful also with SELinux. The default configuration will prevent your virtual hosts directories from being accessed by httpd. You will need to set the appropriate context:

```
# chcon -R -u system_u -r object_r -t httpd_sys_content_t <DocumentRoot>
```

Another option is just to disable SELinux.